# finding thermocline using depth and temperature

Tags: algorithm, derivative

temp = {23,23,23,22,20,20,19,12,11,10,10 };
depth= {0,1,2,3, 8, 9, 10, 12, 18, 23, 29 };

I have two arrays as shown i need to find thermocline using the following statement

it is easily see that the slope of the curve (i.e. dT/dh) is a maximum at the (very!) obvious thermocline.
 Furthermore, because the curvature of the curve changes at the thermocline, a point of inflection, then, by definition d2T/dx2 = 0.
 Another way to look at it is that to maximise the slope, i.e. the 1st  derivative, 
 then the 2nd derivative must be equal to zero.

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: So far declared array, assigned values found maximum and minimum temperature.

Comment: Can you determine the the 1st derivative and 2nd derivative array ?

Comment: No i don't know how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by h in (dT/dh) , and what do you mean by x in (d2T/dx2)?